# How to redirect to another page after a function is triggered [PHP]

Tags: php, redirect

(I'm new here so forgive me if this question is dumb)

Hello i'm looking for a solution to redirect to another page after a certain function is called. For example

```
if (condition is true) {
redirect ()}

function redirect() {
redirect
}
```

I can't use the header function here because

> header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make absolutely sure that the user gets redirected, I think letting PHP handle the redirect is the best approach. This means that you either have to make sure that no HTML/spaces are outputted first (preferred), or use output buffering control with the `ob_start()` function at the beginning of your script.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Then you can use a PHP redirect just fine.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```html
if () {
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;pagehere.php' />";
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Yea, but in this condition user can select not to redirect in some browsers such as firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can write javascript with php that will be interpreted as soon as it is read by the browser..:

```
<?
if(...)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response but i want to make sure that the user is redirected. So i  will go with @Nicasus's response

Comment: indeed, but the question was clearly without php header, you're welcome